# Issue Running 'docker exec' Command: 'the input device is not a TTY' Error

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm encountering an issue when executing the command: '`docker exec -it MysqlContainer bash`.'

The problem I'm facing is that it says 'the input device is not a TTY. If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty.'

I'm new to using Docker, and I need help resolving this problem. Can anyone please assist me ?